# getting error "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriPartException"

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, aws

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.2. I am getting following error in error_log after moving the site on new server (AWS Server):

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriPartException:
>   Host "[IP ADDRESS]" is not valid or is not accepted by Zend\Uri\Http
>   in /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php:746

anyone have idea how to fix this error?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Camit1dk, I didn't find any solution yet but I am able to find root cause of this issue.

Comment: Whats the reason of this? @LalitKaushik